# Redirect to homepage if user is not admin and page is woocommerce page

Tags: wordpress

I'm trying to create a WP Function to redirect all users except admins to the homepage if destination url is a woocommerce page.

I've found the following code snippet online:

```
add_action( 'wp', 'ts_redirect_product_pages', 99 );
 
function ts_redirect_product_pages() {
     
    if ( is_product() | is_shop() | is_product_category() | is_product_tag() | is_cart() | is_checkout() | is_account_page() ) {
        wp_safe_redirect( home_url() );
        exit;
    } 
}
```

Which is working fine for all type of users. So I tried to add !is_admin() this way:

```
add_action( 'wp', 'ts_redirect_product_pages', 99 );
 
function ts_redirect_product_pages() {
     
    if ( !is_admin() && is_product() | is_shop() | is_product_category() | is_product_tag() | is_cart() | is_checkout() | is_account_page() ) {
        wp_safe_redirect( home_url() );
        exit;
    } 
}
```

Which is not working. I guess I'm doing something wrong with the !is_admin() && part of code.

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

First of all, I want to point out some mistakes and want to add some suggestions.

**Mistakes**

1. `|` This is not a **OR** you need to use double `||` to make an OR statement.
2. `is_admin()` people generally think this function makes a check as **is the user an administrator** 
   This function makes a check for **administrative interface page** not for user **current user role**
   is a simple word this function checks if the current page is the backend page or frontend page.
   Check [is_admin](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_admin/) documentation for more information.

**Suggestions**

- You can use the `wp` hook for redirecting but I won't suggest it. Instead of using `wp`, you should use the `template_redirect` hook.
  as the says, it's for redirect usage.
  Check [template_redirect](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/template_redirect/) documentation for more information.

**Solution for your Question**

As I explained above `is_admin` is not the correct function for an administration check. As we know `administration` is a role, so we'll have to get the current user and get its roles and check if `administration` is one of the current user roles or not.

code below has a function `vh_wp_is_admin_role()` that return `true` or `false` for admin role check.
We will use this function to check if the user is an admin then we will check if for the current pages.

I am using nested if checks but you can do single-line checks as well. It's on you.

```
/**
 * Get the current user's roles.
 *
 * @return array
 */
function vh_wp_is_admin_role() {
    // Check if the user is logged in.
    if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
        // Get current user.
        $user = wp_get_current_user();
        // Get user role.
        $roles = (array) $user->roles;
        // check if the user has an admin role.
        return in_array( 'administrator', $roles, true );
    }

    // Set default to false.
    return false;
}

/**
 * Redirect users to the home page if they visit
 * the WooCommerce pages.
 * - This redirect will ignore admin users
 * - This redirect will be applied for non-logged in users as well.
 */
function vh_wc_redirect_product_pages() {
    // If the user is not admin.
    // Note: this check will be set to false for the non-loggedin user as well.
    // If you don't want to apply to redirect your logic for non-logged in users
    // then you'll have to make is_user_logged_in() check before this check.
    if ( ! vh_wp_is_admin_role() ) {
        if ( is_product() || is_shop() || is_product_category() || is_product_tag() || is_cart() || is_checkout() || is_account_page() ) {
            wp_safe_redirect( home_url() );
            exit;
        }
    }
}
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'vh_wc_redirect_product_pages' );
```